# I can't get my CSS code to work properly

Tags: html, css

this is my first post. Despite all efforts, I seem to be a total noob, clearly missing something very simple. I can't get my CSS code to work properly. Here is how:

This is my simple HTML code: (something.html in this example)

```
<!doctype html> 
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="something.css">
    <title>yolo</title>
</head>
<body text="black" background="83467_0003b.jpg">
    <h1><center><font face="Arial">Hello World.</font></center></h1>
    <a href="something.html"><center><b>Click here</b></center></a> 
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my CSS code: (something.css in this example)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-image: url("83467_0003b.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
a {
    color: yellow;
    background-color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

</body>
```

*Now, I can't get the background image to stop repeating itself;

*I can only use the plain "a" to give new attributes to the link (only color, background color doesn't work). If I use "a: link" the link goes back to its default attributes.

What should I do?

- U P D A T E *  The problem is solved. I accidentally put html tags in the css code X(  Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Just to clarify: you don’t _actually_ have `<html>` etc. in your CSS file, do you?

Comment: Another thing is you may have clicked the link. In this case you may have to make a style for a:selected also

Comment: The link background-color does not work because you use the `<center>` tag within the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the style from body otherwise the tag style override the css in external file

```
<!doctype html> 
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="something.css">
    <title>yolo</title>
  </head>
  <body >
    <h1><center><font face="Arial">Hello World.</font></center></h1>
    <a href="something.html"><center><b>Click here</b></center></a> 
  </body>
```

In .css file use  only css statement no HTML o javascript code

**something.css**

```
body {
    background-image: url("83467_0003b.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
a {
    color: yellow;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I accidentally used html tags in css.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS file must only contain:

```
body {
  background-image: url("83467_0003b.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
a {
  color: yellow;
  background-color: white;
}
```

In something.html in the `<body text="black" background="83467_0003b.jpg">` sintax, the `text` and `background` attributes are incorrects.

If you want to declare CSS inline styles, you could use something like this:

```
<body style="background: url(83467_0003b.jpg); color: black;">
```

However, you can achieve the same results with this code, by keeping the HTML and CSS validation:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("83467_0003b.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  background-color: white;
  color: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
}
h1 {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="something.css">
  <title>yolo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello World.</h1>
  <a href="something.html">
    Click here
  </a>
</body>

</html>
```